# Why does reader.GetOrdinal("FieldName") throw an exception?

Tags: ado.net, field, exists, sqldatareader, ordinal

this throws an exception, when the field does not exist:

`reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FieldName"))` => bang

Why not return -1 ?

Comment: Following you logic... why do we need exception at all?

Comment: Why not return -1 like in reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.IndexOf("FieldName") ? btw. the IndexOf always returns -1 LOL...

Comment: :) But here you usually pass this value to other methods of the reader, and it will take more logic to handle this -1.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess here.

The common pattern for this method is to call *GetOrdinal* for column name and then call *GetXXX()* methods with given ordinal which is faster than do a search by column's name every time.

Therefore in case of exception here we fail fast and we can't ignore it. Wihtout exception we will try to find a column that doesn't exist and then try to find a field by given ordinal (without checking for -1 which is very easy to omit in this case) and only here we will realise that something went wrong few steps before (may be even too many steps before).